# Action object Form Object Command Object

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, action

Can someone explain in the context of a Web application what do these mean? I am reading up on Spring MVC reference and see these terms thrown around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are referring to a bean that is the the target for the data in the form fields.  I.e if you have a Person bean with username, address, email etc etc then you might have a registration.jsp with a form that your users enter all these various details, with an attribute path set in the form tag, e.g. path="username" etc.     Once they post the form all the information that they have entered will be matched up from the path attributes and mapped to the corresponding appropriate fields in your Person class.

Example jsp:

```
<form:form ... commandName="person">
  <input type="text" ...  path="username">
```

Person class

```
Private String username;
```

Spring docs here: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html